# Hugging face model arphanghoshal/ emoroberta is very slow

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, sentiment-analysis, pre-trained-model

```
from transformers import RobertaTokenizerFast, TFRobertaForSequenceClassification, pipeline

tokenizer = RobertaTokenizerFast.from_pretrained("arpanghoshal/EmoRoBERTa")

model = TFRobertaForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("arpanghoshal/EmoRoBERTa")

emotxt = pipeline('sentiment-analysis', 

                model='arpanghoshal/EmoRoBERTa')

emotions  = emotxt(query)

emotions
```

how the model will give a response in a few second.?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Ironically, Community Bot wasn't really specific enough there, was it. How slow is it currently? Does it give a reasonable result at the end, and is it equally slow on every run and every query? What hardware are you using - do you have a GPU and how much memory does it have. (And does `nvidia-smi` change when loading it, to confirm it is being used).